# Angularjs - Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-injector

I'm trying to to use the [Angular UI Bootstrap module](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), in specific the Modal plugin.
My app-folder is structured in this way:

- app

  - scheda

    - scheda.html
    - schedacontroller.js
  - app.js
- css
- ...
- index.html

This is **app.js**, the main app file:

```
// created the module GasistaFelice
// also included ngRoute for all our routing needs

angular.module('ngGasistaFelice', [])
.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.gasID = "10"; //default value
});

angular.module('ngGasistaFelice', ['ui.bootstrap']);

var GasistaFelice = angular.module('ngGasistaFelice', ['ngRoute']);

GasistaFelice.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
// route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'app/ordinare/ordinare.html',
                controller  : 'orderController'
            })

            // route for the paniere page
            .when('/:id/gasmember/:id/basket', {
                templateUrl : 'app/paniere/paniere.html',
                controller  : 'paniereController'
            })

            // route for the scheda page
            .when('/:id/profile', {
                templateUrl : 'app/scheda/scheda.html',
                controller  : 'schedaController'
            })

            // route for the conto page
            .when('/:id/gasmember/:id/cash', {
                templateUrl : 'app/conto/conto.html',
                controller  : 'contoController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
    }]);
```

exc....

This is the controller of the page in which i want to put the Modal plugin:

```
var app = angular.module('ngGasistaFelice', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('schedaController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $modal, $log, $http) {
        var id = $routeParams.id;
        // --- URL finale --- 
        //var url = 'http://localhost:8000/gasistafelice/api/v1/person/id/?format=json';
        //URL di prova

        $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

          $scope.open = function (size) {

            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
              controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
              size: size,
              resolve: {
                items: function () {
                  return $scope.items;
                }
              }
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
              $scope.selected = selectedItem;
            }, function () {
              $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
          };
```

When i load the page containing the schedaController, i keep getting this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] h ttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeParamsProvider%20%3C-%20%24routeParams
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost/GasistaFelice2_angular/js/angular.min.js:6:450
    at http://localhost/GasistaFelice2_angular/js/angular.min.js:35:431
    at Object.c [as get] (http://localhost/GasistaFelice2_angular/js/angular.min.js:34:13)
    at http://localhost/GasistaFelice2_angular/js/angular.min.js:35:499
    at c (http://localhost/GasistaFelice2_angular/js/angular.min.js:34:13)
    at d (http://localhost/GasistaFelice2_angular/js/angular.min.js:34:230)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost/GasistaFelice2_angular/js/angular.min.js:34:394)
    at http://localhost/GasistaFelice2_angular/js/angular.min.js:66:112
    at http://localhost/GasistaFelice2_angular/js/angular.min.js:53:14
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defining `angular.module('ngGasistaFelice', [])` multiple times with different required modules (inside of the second parameter to the `module` function):

```
angular.module('ngGasistaFelice', [])
angular.module('ngGasistaFelice', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var GasistaFelice = angular.module('ngGasistaFelice', ['ngRoute']);
var app = angular.module('ngGasistaFelice', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

...specifically, the last one is the one you're trying to use `ngRoute` with, and you haven't even injected it there.

A better solution is to define it once, say:

```
var GasistaFelice = angular.module('ngGasistaFelice', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngRoute'
]);
```

And then you could do what you were trying to do:

```
GasistaFelice.controller(...);
```

Or, if you need this in another file (or scope) and `GasistaFelice` is not yet defined, you can get it by calling `angular.module` **without** passing the required dependencies, like:

```
var app = angular.module('ngGaistaFelice');
app.controller(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since version 0.14.0 angular team prefixed all components you have to use, look [more](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Migration-guide-for-prefixes#modal). For your case you need
Change: $modal for $uibModal.
Change: $modalInstance for $uibModalInstance.
Change: modal-transclude for uib-modal-transclude

Comment: Was thrown by an older Pluralsight video, thank you for this tidbit!